# Merge small pandas dataframe into larger, copying values by rule

Tags: python, pandas

There are two dataframes, both with datetime objects in either 5 min, `df_05min`, or 15 min, `df_15min`, increments.

```
df_05min = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2008-10-2404:12:30',
                                '2008-10-2404:12:35',
                                '2008-10-2404:12:40',
                                '2008-10-2404:12:45',
                                '2008-10-2404:12:50',
                                '2008-10-2404:13:00',
                                '2008-10-2404:13:05']})

df_15min = pd.DataFrame([['2008-10-2404:12:15',  'L'],
                        ['2008-10-2404:12:30',  'r'],
                        ['2008-10-2404:12:45',  'S'  ],
                        ['2008-10-2404:13:00',  'L'],
                        ['2008-10-2404:13:15',  'L' ]], columns=['dt','col'])
```

The goal is to merge the `df_15min` dataframe into the `df_05min` dataframe on the datetime column, `dt`, copying some accompanying data into the appropriate rows.  This is instead of an outer merge where non-matching values get `NaN`. For example, in `df_15min` '2008-10-2404:12:30' has a value of `np.nan` that I would like to copy to the 5 minute values belonging to that 15 min interval in `df_05min` .  This means 12:30, 12:35, and 12:40 will all have values of `np.nan`.

The desired end product looks like this:

```
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(['2008-10-2404:12:15', 'L',
                        '2008-10-2404:12:30', 'r',
                        '2008-10-2404:12:35', 'r',
                        '2008-10-2404:12:40', 'r',
                        '2008-10-2404:12:45', 'S',
                        '2008-10-2404:12:50', 'S',
                        '2008-10-2404:13:00', 'L',
                        '2008-10-2404:13:15', 'L'])
```

Comment: No `'2008-10-2404:13:05'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here need [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with outer join, what is not implemented, so possible solution is [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), sort by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), forward filling missing values and last create default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_05min = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2008-10-24 04:12:30',
                                '2008-10-24 04:12:35',
                                '2008-10-24 04:12:40',
                                '2008-10-24 04:12:45',
                                '2008-10-24 04:12:50',
                                '2008-10-24 04:13:00',
                                '2008-10-24 04:13:05']})

df_15min = pd.DataFrame([['2008-10-24 04:12:15',  'L'],
                        ['2008-10-24 04:12:30',  'r'],
                        ['2008-10-24 04:12:45',  'S'  ],
                        ['2008-10-24 04:13:00',  'L'],
                        ['2008-10-24 04:13:15',  'L' ]], columns=['dt','col'])

df_05min['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_05min['dt'])
df_15min['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_15min['dt'])

df=pd.merge(df_05min, df_15min, how='outer').sort_values('dt').ffill().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
                   dt col
0 2008-10-24 04:12:15   L
1 2008-10-24 04:12:30   r
2 2008-10-24 04:12:35   r
3 2008-10-24 04:12:40   r
4 2008-10-24 04:12:45   S
5 2008-10-24 04:12:50   S
6 2008-10-24 04:13:00   L
7 2008-10-24 04:13:05   L
8 2008-10-24 04:13:15   L
```

Comment: @U9-Forward - No, there is changed order of operation, I am surprised your solution working. Because first is necessary sorting, then replace missing values.

Comment: Eeek! and `pd.merge`

Comment: @U9-Forward - So do you think your order is correct?

Comment: Nope, as you said

Answer (score 1):

Try using `merge` with `how='outer'`, `fillna`, and `sort_values`:

```
print(df_05min.merge(df_15min,how='outer').ffill().sort_values('dt'))
```

Output:

```
                   dt col
7  2008-10-2404:12:15   L
0  2008-10-2404:12:30   r
1  2008-10-2404:12:35   r
2  2008-10-2404:12:40   r
3  2008-10-2404:12:45   S
4  2008-10-2404:12:50   S
5  2008-10-2404:13:00   L
6  2008-10-2404:13:05   L
8  2008-10-2404:13:15   L
```

If you care about index, use:

```
print(df_05min.merge(df_15min,how='outer').ffill().sort_values('dt').reset_index(drop=True))
```